# CSS width animation not working when clicking tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is a stripped down version of something I'm working on. Basically I have a series of tabs that when clicked on, show a different picture. When I click on the tab, I want to animate the overflow width, revealing the `.show` content. I can't figure out why things are not animating. FYI, I'm doing this in Chrome.

[**LIVE CODE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEyzH)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li class="active" data-tab="1">Slide 1</li>
      <li data-tab="2">Slide 2</li>
      <li data-tab="3">Slide 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-wrapper">

    <div class="tab active" data-slide="1">
      <div class="overflow">
        <div class="show"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" data-slide="2">
      <div class="overflow">
        <div class="show"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab" data-slide="3">
      <div class="overflow">
        <div class="show"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div><!--/.container-->
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background:#999999;
}
ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
li {
  display:table-cell;
  color:#ffffff;
}
li.active {
  color:blue;
}
.tab-wrapper {
  width:800px;
  height:300px;
  border-top:solid 20px #ffffff;
}
.tab {
  width:800px;
  height:300px;
  position:relative;
  background:#666666;
  display:none;
}
.tab.active {
  display:block;
}
.overflow {
  width:0%;
  height:100%;
  border:solid 3px red;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition:width 1s ease;
}
.tab.active .overflow {
  width:100%;
  -webkit-transition:width 1s ease;
}
[data-slide="1"] .show {
  width:800px;
  height:200px;
  top:50px;
  position:absolute;
}
[data-slide="1"] .show { background:yellow; }
[data-slide="2"] .show { background:green; }
[data-slide="3"] .show { background:blue; }
```

JS:

```
$('.tabs li').click(function() {

  var tab = $(this).data('tab');
  var picked = $('.tab').data('slide', tab);

  $('.tabs li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.tab.active').removeClass('active');

  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('.tab[data-slide=' + tab + ']').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You have `width:0` set via the `style` attribute (through jQuery’s `.css`) – and that has a higher specificity than your `.tab.active .overflow` rule that tries to set `width:100%`. Instead of hiding the elements that way, use matching CSS rules (than can be overwritten by a `:hover` rule with same or higher specificity).

Comment: @CBroe I've updated the code, but it's still not animating... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `transition`/`animation` **WILL NOT WORK** in a div that has `display: none;` property.

It will not work either if that div has a parent with `display: none;` property.

Instead you can try giving a `position` of `absolute` value to the `.tab`s and make the initial width of `0px`. Then set `800px` of width when it have the `.active` class. In this case, you need to apply the `transition` on the `.tab` not on the `.overflow` div.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/uwt11zbu/)** here.

Comment: ah interesting, i didn't know that, but it totally makes sense now that i think about it. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and removing class try using slideToggle():

```
$('.tab').click(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.overflow').slideToggle();
    }
);
```

And in css give prefered width and height for the .overflow.

Comment: can't seem to get that to work. would you be willing up to update my codepen so i can see what you mean?